# JQuery next() vs selection by id

Tags: jquery, performance

Which is better in terms of performance:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_abc');
```

or

```
$(this).next();
```

assuming objects:

```
< div id='a' >
< div id='a_abc' >
```

?

how to write tags here?

Comment: To write inline code-style, enclose the content in backticks `` -- the result is `like this`.

Comment: You really should access the `id` property directly, like so: `this.id` - it saves you a few (unnecessary) function calls, and makes your code a bit easier to write and read. So: `$('#' + this.id + '_abc');`

Comment: Interesting [jsPerf results](http://jsperf.com/id-selector-vs-next), particularly the difference between using `this.id` and `$(this).attr('id')`.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions based on your question

As always, remember that as a developer, your time is typically the most valuable resource. Do not focus on optimization of selector speed unless it is clear that performance needs to be improved.

Taken from 
http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: I think, once you get grip on optimal code, you wont waste any time afterwards, but it will be as indicator that you do care about code quality ;)

Comment: @TomTom Your statement is valid if we take it as a general argument apply to most of the languages, but in case you of Jquery thinking about which "Jquery selector" gives a more speed may not be of much use because if you profile it yourself and check the difference is not more than a few milliseconds, and now a days browsers are processing JavaScript so fast that anyone would hardly see any difference even if  you use "the slow one" a hundred times in your page.

Comment: keep in mind, that I can have 10k similar objects in one page, then this difference can be noticeable, as nowadays we get more and more JavaScript rich web pages. This particular question arose when I tested JQuery plugin.

Comment: @TomTom yes that is true if you have that code 10k times then it might cause a second delay which will become noticable to the users.

Answer (score 1):

The first one uses `document.getElementById` internally, and you can't get any better than that performancewise. The second one probably uses DOM traversal, which is not very efficient, but you'll probably never notice the difference anyway.